# azure cannot get the new values on the database

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I'm using in my web application singleton in order to caching some texts which are stored in my MSSQL database. Now I've added some new texts to the database. On my local machine, the application can get them, but if I deploy the application on azure, it cannot get the new texts on the database. Do I have to restart the application? If yes, how can you restart your website on azure?

Comment: What database? What values? Please edit your question with more details, as it currently isn't really clear.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, now better?

Comment: Well... I still don't understand the question. There should never be a need to restart an app just to read from a database. Probably a good idea to edit your app to show your code, and what error you're getting.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, if you use singleton, or static variables, do you have to restart the application to reset them?

Comment: Could you please post more relevant codes about how you cache the texts form MSSQL?  In which method you used to get the SQL value? As far as I know the static variables will be changed, if you set the new value to it. We don't have to restart the application.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you could try to [remote debug your web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#a-nameremotedebugaremote-debugging-web-apps) to make sure the code of retrieving data from database and caching datasets work as expected.

Secondly, please make sure you could connect to your database after you deploy your web app on Azure. If your Azure web app need to access on-premises SQL server, you could [create a hybrid connection between App Service and an on-premises SQL Server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-hybrid-connection-get-started). If you are using Azure SQL database, please make sure you enabled **Azure connections** to allow applications from Azure to connect to your Azure SQL server.